# Calling F# from Excel 2002/03: "Automation error"

Tags: .net, excel, vba, f#, activex

I'm trying to call F# from Excel (2002) but get "Automation error" when I try to create a new instance of my class.
I run regasm in post-build, add reference, placed Excel.Exe.Config in Office10 folder (with .NET version 4.0.30319.1) and this is my class:

```
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)>]
[<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid "F348766A-B63D-41FE-824C-27989266A535">]
type Provider () =
    member __.Compile s = Compiler.compile s
```

And the Compiler module has its own attributes with a different Guid.
The error is in this line:

```
Set p = New MCTE.Provider
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message isn't very useful :-(.. any chance to find some more details about the error? Also, how complex is your F# code? Did you try the same thing in C#?

Comment: Created an empty C# project, a single class (with those attributes, different GUID), a single extremely simple method - still failing on the constructor.

Comment: Are you running regasm with the /codebase option? Is your COM object x86 or x64?